# How to edit the proportion of dataset after downloading from Roboflow

Tags: python, deep-learning, dataset, yolo, roboflow

I'm trying to use Roboflow to train my own model now, and, however, I found a well-annotated dataset with a weird proportion in train, valid, and test.

Hence, I would like to revise the ratio in Python after I download the dataset, but I didn't find any useful information in the Roboflow documentation.

Is there a recommended way to do so in Python?

Answer (score 0):

There’s the option to upload the project to a workspace of your own, and update the train/valid/test split when confirming addition of the labelled images to the full Dataset, or during the marked Step (2) in version Generation.

[image: Roboflow Generate - Update Splits]

I recommend the above process because you will need to update all annotation files manually too if you move image splits manually. If you do the process in Roboflow, everything is taken care of for you.

https://docs.roboflow.com/exporting-data